# How can I target Google Ads to users with higher social class and income?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, geotargeting, cpc-ads, ad-targeting

As an advertiser trying to get customers/leads to sell a product, I notice that Google optimizes my CPC by slowly "slipping" to lower-class targets. This makes my campaigns cheaper but less productive, as my product is not intended for low-income customers.

More precisely, I can geolocalize people visiting my website. I check visitors location using IP geolocalization. I see that initially visitors come from area like Manhattan and later they come from Queens/Brooklyn/Bronx/NewJersey. I also check visitors platform and I see increasing proportion of people using old operating systems (Windows XP/Vista), also a sign of lower-revenue I guess. Simultaneously I see CPC dropping.

I would rather keep a higher CPC but stick with mid to high revenue targets. I guess many products are intended for target from a certain income level, so this is an issue for many marketers, right?

Comment: I tagged this as "Google AdWords" because you are buying ads.  AdSense is for when you are showing ads on your website.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to target people by household income depending upon the Country. Ref: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2580383?hl=en

Even if you don't use household income targeting, the quality of your leads will improve with time provided you use a smart bidding strategy like target CPA bidding. If low-end devices and operating systems don't result in conversions, the impressions on those devices will gradually begin to decrease over time.